# What is the difference between these two statements (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Does any one know the difference, if any, of the following statements?

```
_context.AddObject(user);

_context.Users.AddObject(user);
```

as well as

```
_context.Attach(user);

_context.Users.Attach(user);
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

Sorry some confusion:

I know the difference between AddObject and Attach, what I meant was is there any difference in the way you use AddObject i.e.

```
_context.AddObject(user);
_context.Users.AddObject(user);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ObjectContext can have multiple sets with the same schema, so it's normally better to use the explicit set. ie `_context.Users.AddObject(user);`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee473442.aspx):

> In the .NET Framework version 4, we recommend that you use methods on
>   the ObjectSet object to perform create, read, delete, attach, and
>   update operations. ObjectSet derives from ObjectQuery, so it also
>   works as a query object.
>
> In versions starting with .NET Framework version 4, you can use the
>   following methods defined on ObjectSet instead of the equivalent ones
>   defined on ObjectContext:
>
> ```
>  AddObject   
>  Attach
>  ApplyCurrentValues
>  ApplyOriginalValues
>  DeleteObject
>  Detach
> ```

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx)

Summary:

`AddObject` sets object state to `Added`, `Attach` sets it to `Unchanged`. If you call `SaveChanges()` method afterwards, context will try to insert an object added by `AddObject` to the storage, while an object added by `Attach` will be deemed unchanged and no actions will be performed for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple difference because your examples are incorrect. It is not

```
context.AddObject(user)
```

but

```
context.AddObject("UserEntitySet", user)
```

If you use `AddObject` or `Attach` directly on context you must tell context which set you want to add or attach your object to wheres if you use the implementation directly on `ObjectSet` it already has this information wrapped in strongly typed way.

IMHO those methods exist only as backward compatibility with EFv1 (.NET 3.5 SP1) where `ObjectSet` didn't exist.